Installed Windows 11 and I am not seeing tags in vscode




All of the above might be related to one problem, I installed Windows 11 from Windows 10 and I open VS Code and I am not able to enable tag parser
settings.json file below:
{
   "files.associations": {
      "systemconfig.h": "c"
  },
  "editor.definitionLinkOpensInPeek": false,
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Default Dark+",
  "workbench.preferredDarkColorTheme": "Default Dark+",
  "extensions.closeExtensionDetailsOnViewChange": true,
  "C_Cpp.autocompleteAddParentheses": true,
  "C_Cpp.inlayHints.autoDeclarationTypes.enabled": false,
  "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine": "default",
  "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "enabled",
  "C_Cpp.workspaceSymbols": "All",
  "editor.multiCursorModifier": "ctrlCmd"
}

I was expecting to have tag parsers. I uninstalled and re-installed extensions and vscode, it didn't help

Which "tags" were you referring to? That word can match too many things.

I am referring to variable tagging to its definition. Before installing Windows 11 everything was fine. I was able to F10 or right click "Go To Definition" or "Ctrl+Left clicking" and was navigated successfully. After installing windows 11, the variables are not color-coded anymore, meaning the definitions are not linked. I made all the changes on intellisense I could find online, didn't help. Not sure what I am missing

By changing the operating system, your C++ toolset can be easily broken and requires some manual fixes. That won't be an easy task but you should get started from Microsoft C++ extension logging, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/enable-logging-cpp to see what's wrong with the language server.

Idk what changed, but after a few days, it started populating tags and variable links on its on. Maybe it was an msft update or there is another process initialization involved as part of loading links
